# UIWindow not displaying until method complete

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwindow

I'm trying to display a view because the method takes a good few seconds to complete. However, the loading UIWindow doesn't actually become key and visible until the whole method is complete. Any idea what's going on here?

```
// this line creates a uiwindow with view controller as root view controller, an activity indicator, and a label and makes the loading view key and visible
[XSELLoadingView presentLoadingViewWithTitle:@"Generating Report"]; // use loading view for long times

// these three lines process a lot of data and present the view on the main window
XSELCount *startCount = [[XSELCount counts] objectAtIndex:[self.startingPick selectedRowInComponent:0]];
XSELCount *endCount = [[XSELCount counts] objectAtIndex:[self.endingPick selectedRowInComponent:0
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[XSELReportView viewWithReportData:[XSELReportData compareStartCount:startCount toEndCount:endCount]] animated:false];   

// this line makes the main view key and visable 
[XSELLoadingView dismissLoadingView];
```

Comment: Just to clarify XSELLoadingView does present a window with a view, not just a view on top of the current window.

Comment: You need to perform the long processing in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Apply your task inside this one.

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //Do background work
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //Update UI
    });
});
```